# Pad string with characters

Tags: perl, printf, pad

I have

```
$data_dec = 7;
$data_bin = sprintf("%08b",data_dec);
```

and $data_bin is

```
00000111
```

How do I pad with "X" instead of zeros while maintaining 8-bits? Expected data:

```
XXXXX111
```

Comment: `$data_bin=sprintf("%8b",$data_dec); $data_bin=~y/ /X/;` ? Do you know that `$data_dec` must be [0,256) ?

Answer (score 1):

```perl
substr( sprintf( "XXXXXXX%b", $n ), -8 )
```

```perl
sprintf( "%8b", $n ) =~ tr/ /X/r
```